# How to read value stored in previous page viewstate

Tags: c#

**Page1**

```
<asp:LinkButton PostBackUrl="Page2.aspx" id="lnkViewFullDetails" runat="server" Text="View Full Details" />
```

**Page2**

```
<asp:LinkButton PostBackUrl="Page1.aspx" id="lnkBack" runat="server" Text="Back to Page1" />

<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hidPageNo" />
```

**Page2.cs:**

```
if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
{
    Page previousPage = Page.PreviousPage;
    HtmlInputHidden pPageNo = (HtmlInputHidden)previousPage.FindControl("hidPageNo");

if (pPageNo != null)
{
   ViewState["PageNo"] = pPageNo.Value;
}
}
```

Now I have to go back to Page1 and I want `ViewState["PageNo"]` value there. How can I get that ?

Comment: you can't you have to save this value in session or querystring. scope of ViewState is only current page

Comment: Have you tried crosspagepostback http://www.webblogsforyou.com/crosspagepostback-access-previouspage-controls-to-nextpage-in-asp-net/ here?

Comment: yes and you can see it is working when i go to page2. Now I want to come back to page1 so the question is can I get viewstate value or not.

Comment: OK fine, then answer is no, you can't. As `neontapir` said, you need to use Session or QueryString Instead of ViewState to fulfill your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the lifecycle of ASP.NET pages, Page 2 is not guaranteed to exist after its Unload event, which happens before the load of Page 1. Session is a better place to store data that spans pages.

Comment: yeah but there would be multiple tabs of same page so I can not use session.

Comment: Fair enough, but your question was specific to ViewState. You may want to ask a different question with more details about your situation if you'd like a solution that didn't involve Session either.